# The kernel of a the projection of vector into $xy$-plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F:R^3 \rightarrow R^3$ be the projection of a vector $v$ into the $xy$-plane of the form $(x,y,0)$, that is$$F(x,y,z) = (x,y,0)$$

Then the kernal of F is the z-axis, that is points of the form (0,0,c). That is $$Ker\; F = \{(a,b,c): a=0, b=0\} = z-axis$$

I don't understand why it is $(0,0,c)$ instead of $(0,0,0)$?

Because as far as I understand that kernel takes everything to the zero point which is something like $F(v)=0$ and here in this case, shouldn't it be $(0,0,0)$? And also, this is the projection onto the $xy$-plane, if it is on the z-axis, it no longer stays on the $xy$-plane.

I am really confused.

Comment: What is $F(0,0,c)$?

Comment: The kernel is all the points that become zero after the linear transformation. Since $F(0,0,c)=0$ then $(0,0,c)$ is in the kernel.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thank you so much for the explanation!

Comment: @CyclotomicField Why do you answer the question that I posed to OP? This is not very helpful, I guess. This problem is trivial. So, OP could have got to the point by themselves.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I didn't read your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Given $F: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ then $\textbf{Ker}(F) = F^{-1}(\vec{0}) = \{(0,0,c)\} \Rightarrow a = b = 0$.